# pattern match list a with list b

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I am fairly new to Python.

I have two lists

List A [a, b, c] 
List B [c,d,e,f,g,h]

I would like to re.match (or re.search) list A variables in list B. If any variable from  list A not present in List B, it should return false.

In above lists, it should return false.

Can I try for loop as below ?

for x in listA:
 if re.match(listB, x) 
 return false

Comment: Why do you want to use regular expressions for this?

Comment: @squiguy: perhaps because List A contains regular expressions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `all`:

```
>>> lis1 =  ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
>>> lis2 =  ['c','d','e','f','g','h']
>>> all(x in lis2 for x in lis1)
False
```

If `lis2` is huge convert it to a `set` first, as sets provide `O(1)` lookup:

```
>>> se = set(lis2)
>>> all(x in se for x in lis1)
False
```

Regular expressions don't work on lists.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for sets, not regular expressions:

```
 set(listA) & set(listB) == set(listA)
```

The above is stating: if the intersection of the two sets has the same  elements than the first set, then all of the first set's elements are also present in the second set. Or, as Jon points out, a solution based in set difference is also possible:

```
 not set(listA) - set(listB)
```

The above states: If there are no elements that are in the first set that are not present in the second set, then the condition holds (sorry about the double negation!)

Comment: If using sets, at the very least it should be `not set(a).difference(b)`

Comment: Note that using the `.difference` method doesn't require the other iterable to be a `set` so it saves time on conversion (and it also enables more than one iterable to be present if you really wanted)

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the lists, and use `all`.

```
>>> llist = "a b c".split()
>>> rlist = "c d e".split()
>>> all(re.match(left, right) for left in llist for right in rlist)
False
```

This only becomes interessant if llist contains "true" regexps:

```
>>> llist = [r"^.+foo$", r"^bar.*$"]
>>> rlist = ["foozzz", "foobar"]
>>> all(re.match(left, right) for left in llist for right in rlist)
False
```